# openSAML Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)

Tags: android, maven, opensaml

If I add the opensaml to pom.xml for my Android app then it results in this error.

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)

I know that potential reason for this error is some conflict with the core-library. One conflict is the xcerces so I added an exception for that

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>                    
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

But still the same error is coming.

Comment: Just out of curiosoty, why do you want to add OpenSAML in you android app? Is it or webservice authentication